# svm_learn command of svm_light not working

Tags: c, ubuntu, svm

I am following this tutorial http://svmlight.joachims.org/ to set up SVMLight on my laptop, running Ubuntu 11.10

While attempting to run the `svm_learn`,

`command svm_learn example1/train.dat example1/model`
as shown in the Inductive SVM section. I get the error

```
svm_learn: command not found
```

I checked up on the internet but I found no solutions to this problem.

PS : I am running the command from the svm_light folder that contains the extracted contents of the SVMLight archive.

Please help.

Comment: thanks. I realized that later. Stupid error. :)

Answer (score 5):

You should try **./svm_learn train_File.dat**

and you will get a model file , don't forget to download SVM-Light ( Source Code or Binaries )

Answer (score 0):

./svm_learn ../example1/train.dat ../example1/model